# What is the HTMLness bit?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment):

> The **Range.createContextualFragment()** method returns a DocumentFragment by invoking the HTML fragment parsing algorithm or the XML fragment parsing algorithm with the start of the range (the parent of the selected node) as the context node. The HTML fragment parsing algorithm is used if the range belongs to a Document whose **HTMLness bit** is set.

What is the HTMLness bit they talk about here? I could find almost no info online.

Comment: Sounds like an implementation detail that is used to determine whether to use the HTML fragment parsing algorithm or the XML fragment parsing algorithm.

Comment: I'm guessing that the HTMLness bit is set if the document begins with `<html>` as opposed to `<?xml>`

Comment: @phuzi could be, just couldn't find it being explicitly said anywhere.

Comment: I found this https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2009OctDec/0022.html